# Why is this animation incorrect?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to implement a table (based on CSS-grid at the moment) with a row that is hidden. Upon clicking somewhere, that row should smoothly expand. I want contents of this row to be visible **and preserve their correct size** during the animation.

This is very similar to [this demo](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/ui-element-samples/animated-clip/), but I'm not implementing a menu. But the fact that in that demo, contents ("Menu item 1", "Menu item 2", ...) have constant size during animation is something I want.

I want to implement this using a [FLIP technique as described here](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/) to achieve high framerate with ease.

I've added `scaleY(0.01)` on the row, and `scaleY(100)` on the inner wrapper, in a hope they would cancel out and thus maintain scale. I also added `transform-origin: 0 0` hoping the top edge of the animated row will stay in the same place during the animation.

However, what happens is that the contents are initially way too tall. They also appear to be moving along the Y axis, even when I set `transform-origin: 0 0` (but that might be just the effect of the incorrect height).

I tried using `Element.animate()` as well as manual `element.style.transform = ...` approaches, to no avail.

**My question:** why the hidden row isn't animated properly (the height of its contents isn't constant and they appear to move along Y axis)? How to fix this?

```js
let collapsed = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".collapsed"));

collapsed.forEach((row, idx) => {
  row.dataset["collapsedIdx"] = idx;
  document.querySelector("label").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let collapsedSelf = row.getBoundingClientRect();
    let rowsBelow = Array.from(
      row.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[data-collapsed-idx='${idx}'] ~ *`)
    );

    row.classList.remove("collapsed");
    let expandedSelf = row.getBoundingClientRect();
    let diffY = expandedSelf.height - collapsedSelf.height;

    let animationTiming = {
      duration: 2000,
      easing: "linear"
    };

    let wrapper = row.querySelector(":scope > *");

    row.animate(
      [{ transform: `scaleY(0.01)` }, { transform: `scaleY(1)` }],
      animationTiming
    );

    wrapper.animate(
      [{ transform: `scaleY(100) ` },
       { transform: `scaleY(1) ` }],
      animationTiming
    );

    rowsBelow.forEach((rowBelow) => {
      rowBelow.animate([
        { transform: `translateY(-${diffY}px)` },
        { transform: `translateY(0)` }
      ], animationTiming);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

.subsection {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

label, p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.collapsible,
.collapsible > * {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  will-change: transform;
  contain: content;
}

.collapsed {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* .collapsed {
  transform: scaleY(.2);
}

.collapsed > * {
  transform: scaleY(5)
}

*:nth-child(8),
*:nth-child(9),
*:nth-child(10),
*:nth-child(11),
*:nth-child(12) { transform: translateY(-35px); }

  */

/* .animate-on-transforms {
  transition: transform 2000ms linear;
} */
```

```html
<section>
    <label><strong>CLICK ME!!!</strong></label>
    <p>Value 1</p>

    <label>Row 2</label>
    <p>Value 2</p>

    <label>Row 3</label>
    <p>Value 3</p>
    <div class="subsection collapsible collapsed">
      <section>
        <label>Subrow 1</label>
        <p>Subvalue 1</p>

        <label>Subrow 2</label>
        <p>Subvalue 2</p>

        <label>Subrow 3</label>
        <p>Subvalue 3</p>

        <label>Subrow 4</label>
        <p>Subvalue 4</p>

      </section>
    </div>

    <label>Row 4</label>
    <p>Value 4</p>

    <label>Row 5</label>
    <p>Value 5</p>

</section>
```

Comment: Er, why do you need Javascript? I think this could be done entirely with CSS3

Comment: @Martin Could it? I think I'd need to animate `height` or `max-height` then, which would not guarantee 60 FPS on slower machines. That's why I'm trying the FLIP technique.

Comment: To me it looks like you got your animation effect wrong. Do you have a prototype displaying the correct/desired animation, even if not as performant as the JS version? For like... 1 element?

Comment: I don't have an alternative implementation of my exact code at hand @AndreiGheorghiu, but I would've probably used a common `max-height` technique, like here: https://codepen.io/brundolf/pen/bqqeye

Comment: I'm considering answering your question, but I want to make sure I understand the desired outcome first. So you simply want a smooth drawer effect? No scaling, 3d rotations, anything like that?

Comment: Here is another example of what I'm after: https://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/zwvNY/. (but in my case the row has preceding / following siblings). Yes, I want the contents of the animated row to not be scaled, not rated. They should be appearing line by line (or rather row of pixels after another) as the container expands. I also want to use `transform` only as in a proper FLIP technique.

Comment: Are you going to post an answer @AndreiGheorghiu? I found the issue, but if you post an answer I'll accept yours :)

Comment: I am going to post an answer, but I'm not adding it for you to accept it. I'm adding it for you to better understand animations (and get better at it). I'm almost done, but I never rush.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the interpolation. You are assuming that at each step of the animation we will always have `scale(x)` and `scale(1/x)` where `x` within `[0,1]` but due to rounding I don't think you will have this.

Here is a basic example:

```css
.box,
p{
 transform-origin:0 0;
 transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  transform:scale(0.1);
}
.box:hover p{
  transform:scale(10);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>
Lorem Ipsume<br>
Lorem Ipsume<br>
Lorem Ipsume<br>
Lorem Ipsume<br>
Lorem Ipsume<br>
</p>
</div>
```

Logically we may think that the text will stay the same but no. It will grow then shrink again. So yes the scales will get cancelled but not along the animation.